# Discord Bot clear command doesn't execute after I added it to other server | Python

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm clearly new to making bot on discord, might aswell python language. I just made a simple local bot which does have a clear command. At first it's working on my server but after when I added it to my friend's server it doesn't clear the amount of messages. I don't know if it's bug but I have the codes here, references just came from other youtubers.

```
@bot.command()                                                                                    
async def clear(ctx, amount=10):
     await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

the code is that simple but it doesn't execute in the server. Idk what happened to it.

Edit:

I just realised there are some errors that has happened while executing that command. The command was being ignored

```
Ignoring exception in command clear:
```

Answer (score 0):

When, as an owner, you invite a bot to your server, you do it via a webpage. The webpage is displaying all the permissions that the bot asks and you can decide to grant it these permissions or not (by unchecking checkboxes).

Your friend might have unchecked some checkboxes when he invited your bot on its server, thus not granting it the permissions it needs to delete messages.

Comment: I see... But as I asked him, he said he didn't. I make the bot Administrator before I sent the link to him. But when I tried to add it on my server the command is working. I didn't uncheck because only the Administrator is checked in it.

Comment: to be clear... there's only one permission to be uncheck, which is the Administrator. Before I added the bot on my friend's server I allow the Administrator permission so the bot can do anything.

Comment: @JesusAnthonyTolentino you can check the permissions granted to a bot after it joined a server from "Server Settings > Integrations > Bots and Apps > Manage". If there is no difference between permissions granted on your server vs on your friend's server, I'm sorry to say I don't have more ideas on how to fix your problem.

Comment: I guess the bot was once originally made from my server. And I also coded it there before adding it to my friend's server. Say what if I delete the Bot application and then create a new one? I'll just have to copy the Token and replace it to the same code that I did. Because I think this was a bug. I didn't mean literal bug,  because when you basically turn online the Bot it runs like how it is on the code, editing it would be like it will confuse somehow idk. The other command is working well on my friend's server except the clear command.